# Don't know how to spawn multiple enemies

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

My code should spawn multiple enemies that chase around my player. Instead, the enemy just stays in one place. This only happens when I try to input a value into the enemy-spawning function for the spawn coordinates. Heres the code:

```
class spawn(object):
def __init__(self,place1,place2):
    self.place1=place1
    self.place2=place2
def AIPrototype(self):#The important parts to this error star here
    global x,y,x1,y1
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,THECOLORS['blue'],(self.place1,self.place2,50,50))
    x1=self.place1
    y1=self.place2#end here
    if x1<x:
        xspeed1=1
        slopex1=x-x1
    if x1>x:
        xspeed1=-1
        slopex1=x1-x
    if y1<y:
        yspeed1=1
        slopey1=y-y1
    if y1>y:
        yspeed1=-1
        slopey1=y1-y       
#
    hypo1=((slopex1**2)+(slopey1**2))**0.5
    speedmark1=hypo1/3
    speedy1=slopey1/speedmark1
    speedx1=slopex1/speedmark1
    movex1=speedx1
    movey1=speedy1
    if x1<=640 and x1>=0:
        if x1>x:
            x1+=xspeed1*movex1
            if x1<x:
                xspeed1=0
    if y1<=480 and x1>=0:
        if y1>y:
            y1+=yspeed1*movey1
            if y1<y:
                yspeed1=0
    if x1<=640 and x1>=0:
        if x1<x:
            x1+=xspeed1*movex1
            if x1>x:
                xspeed1=0
    if y1<=480 and x1>=0:
        if y1<y:
            y1+=yspeed1*movey1
            if y1>y:
                yspeed1=0
#
    if x1>640:
        x1=640
    if x1<0:
        x1=0
    if y1>480:
        y1=480
    if y1<0:
        y1=0 
    self.place1=x1#start
    self.place2=y1#end
```

That's the fucntion for spawning the enemies. The fucntion is called here:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
keepGoing = True        

try:
    while keepGoing:
        clock.tick(60) 

        screen.fill(THECOLORS['red'])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,THECOLORS['green'],(x,y,50,50))
        char()
        spawn1=spawn(200,200)#start
        spawn1.AIPrototype()#end
        pygame.display.flip()
```

I don't know where my error in the coding is, so if someone could help me out, that would be great.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it can be difficult or even impossible to help you.

Comment: Sorry that there's so much code, but i think I cut of all the unimportant parts. These are the parts where I think my error may be in. If i cut out any more, I might cut out the error as well.

Comment: The problem is that your code example is not complete and verifiable. You should provide an example that we can just copy, paste and run. Another problem is the missing documentation and comments that explain how everything is supposed to work. It also looks like you're asking two questions at once: How to spawn multiple enemies and how to move them. The code to move the enemy seems to be broken. I'd suggest to use vectors to handle the movement of the enemies, then you can reduce the whole movement code to a few lines. I can show you an example (do you know how pygame.Sprites work?).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with vectors. To get the velocity of the enemies, I calculate the vector to the player, then normalize it and scale by 4 (the final speed).

```
vel = (player.center - self.pos).normalize() * 4
```

Then you can just add the `vel`ocity to the `pos` and set the `rect.center` to the updated pos vector to move the object.

---

To spawn new enemies, first create a list that should hold the enemy instances and then just `append` new instances when an enemy spawns (press the f-key to spawn them). You can also use [pygame sprites](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13) and sprite groups instead of the Enemy class and the list.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


class Enemy:

    def __init__(self, pos, color):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(pos, (26, 45))
        self.color = color
        self.pos = pg.math.Vector2(pos)

    def update(self, player):
        vel = (player.center - self.pos).normalize() * 4
        self.pos += vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

    def draw(self, screen):
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    bg_color = pg.Color('gray12')
    player_color = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
    enemy_color = pg.Color('sienna1')
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    player = pg.Rect((100, 300), (26, 50))
    enemy_list = [Enemy((100, 300), enemy_color)]

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    enemy_list.append(Enemy((400, 0), enemy_color))

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_a]:
            player.x -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_d]:
            player.x += 5
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            player.y -= 5
        elif keys[pg.K_s]:
            player.y += 5

        for enemy in enemy_list:
            enemy.update(player)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        pg.draw.rect(screen, player_color, player)
        for enemy in enemy_list:
            enemy.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```